# SkiaSharp draw image

Tags: android, xamarin, skia, skiasharp

I'm working on a xamarin application.
In this application i need to draw a picture taken by the phone and draw on it.
For the draw of the picture and every thing else i use SkiaSharp.

I got a problem to draw my picture : 
When i draw it the rotation is not good, so i have rotated my canvas and draw the picture.
Now i don't know how to calculate my translation and my scale i have to applied to the canvas for the picture take all the canvas.

Here is how i draw my picture :

```
            var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(_mediaHelper.OpenStream(ImageUri));
            int rotation = _mediaHelper.GetPhotoRotation(ImageUri);
            canvas.Save();
            canvas.RotateDegrees(rotation, bitmap.Width / 2f, bitmap.Height / 2f);
            canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);
            canvas.Restore();
```

_mediaHelper.OpenStream(ImageUri) is a service provided by the android application to retreive a stream of the picture with the URI.

Here the result of the draw : [image: The picture is croped at the top]

Comment: call `DrawBitmap` with a `Matrix` parameter

Comment: You think that my mistake is to draw the bitmap at the point (0,0)

Comment: yes, use `DrawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)`

Comment: In skiaSharp this method doesn't exist :
public void DrawBitmap(SKBitmap bitmap, SKRect dest, SKPaint paint = null);
public void DrawBitmap(SKBitmap bitmap, SKRect source, SKRect dest, SKPaint paint = null);
public void DrawBitmap(SKBitmap bitmap, float x, float y, SKPaint paint = null);

Comment: so canvas is not: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Canvas.DrawBitmap/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap/Android.Graphics.Matrix/Android.Graphics.Paint/ ?

Comment: No i'm drawing in a librairie project, i need this for Android and Ios,
The canvas is : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/SkiaSharp.SKCanvas/

Comment: aha, ok, so forget what i said ;-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147698/discussion-between-sagon-nicolas-and-pskink).

Comment: Why not redraw the image when rotated